# Calling App.store.commit() too fast in Ember

Tags: ember.js, commit, ember-data

In my application I have a list of items, and a button to delete the last one. Then on my controller I wrote the following action:

```
  removeLastItem: ->
      lastItem = current_order.get('items').get('lastObject')
      lastItem.deleteRecord()
      App.store.commit()
```

My issue comes when **I keep clicking on my button too fast**. At some point it seems that while
the store.commit() has not finished (the item stills dirty), it is already calling the store.commit() for another item, throwing this error:

> Error: Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord` on
>   App.Item:ember6954:f6a1c932-2db0-4933-7c92-69fbd3838229> while
>   in state rootState.deleted.uncommitted. Called with undefined

I already tried to put this code inside a RunLoop or a Transaction, but nothing worked.

Any clues ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a different approach, like for example disabling your button until the record's `didDelete` event is fired.

Example:

```
  removeLastItem: ->
    # get the reference to your button and disable it
    lastItem = current_order.get('items').get('lastObject')
    lastItem.deleteRecord()
    lastItem.on 'didDelete', =>
      # reenable your button again

    lastItem.on 'becameError', =>
      # reenable your button again and notify user?

    App.store.commit()
```

See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/) for info on the model lifecycle and all the events you can listen to.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good one, it is a way to do it indeed, but I think it kills a bit the UI responsiveness that we expect from a Javascript application, doesn't it ?

Comment: well, depends, if you only disable ***the button*** the rest of the UI would still be responsive I guess

Comment: I just implemented your approach, and it works like a charm, the user does not notice any kind of unresponsiveness or whatsoever. From now we will pay huge attention to deal with ember model states in our app, it is an important part of Ember I guess since its all async.

Answer (score 0):

I found another very-simple-approach.

In [this blog post](http://nragaz.com/post/44226445908/patterns-and-anti-patterns-for-ember-data) they notice that we could just use the [ember-data model-cycle flags](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/).

So we could just use this code in our template (suppose the template is user.emblem)

```
if isSaving
  = will show this if some crud action is performing on the user ercord
else
  = good stuff
```