# How can add a disabled attribute in a button

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have the following problem: I want to disable my button through bindAttr. So I have this button:

```
<div class="pull-right refresh-button" style="margin-top: -45px;" 
  title="update Items" {{action refreshItems target="view"}} {{bindAttr 
     disabled="ItemState.isDisable"}}>
  <i class="icon-refresh"></i>
</div>
```

where ItemState.isDisable its an ember object that I’m using for the state. The main idea its when the user click in the button, it can't click anymore until the information comes back from the server...

I'm using ember RC6 and handlebars RC4

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: is there a request/load, similar to jQuery? you can set on the pre-action function for the div disabled attribute to be set to disabled ( disabled="disabled" ) and then re-set it to nothing when the call ends.

Comment: Yes I've been doing that. Before the request, I change the state of atribute to be disabled, but the ember didn't update the binding. When the response comes i change again the state...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different approaches to do this, but the most correct one might be to define a view for your button and put there some logic to handle the state.

For example:

```
MyButton = Ember.View.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['disabled'],
  disabled: function(){
    if (someLogic) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }.property()
});
```

Let me know if it's clear.

You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218832/calling-app-store-commit-too-fast-in-ember/17220961#17220961) also usefull.

Comment: Yes, this help a little. But I understand the problem is in the type of tag... I used a div tag like a button, but this kind of tag its no updated with the disabled. So I change to:
<button type="submit" title="Atualizar Items" {{action refreshItems target="view"}} {{bindAttr disabled="ItemState.isDisable"}} class="btn btn-small pull-right">
                                <i class="icon-refresh"></i>
                            </button>
and its work. Thanks

Comment: you can also define in your view `tagName: 'button'` if you need a different type as the default `div`